# Website not displaying in opera

Tags: html, css, opera

I'm kind of new to web developing and for a school project I have to make a website for a company. It's loading in all the browsers except for Opera 12.xx.
I've uploaded the HTML and CSS to jsfiddle:
[Here is the jsfiddle part](http://www.jsfiddle.net/ByYvu/1/)

```
The part with code is a bit too much, that's why I posted it on jsfiddle.
```

I've got the idea that it's not working because of the nested divs but I can't figure out how to make it work.
btw: images are not working, they are stored locally.

If anyone needs more info, just ask me!

TIA

Answer (score -2):

It's cerntainly not because of the divs

However, i see you're using html 5 tags
i don't know anything about opera but are you certain it supports those html 5 tags?
Opera is the least supportive when it comes to html 5...

Comment: I just converted it from xhtml 1 transitional to html5, it didn't work back then.

Comment: So then what could be the problem?